# 301 redirects on WHMCS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, whmcs

I have installed WHMCS in a subdirectory, **domain.com/whmcs**

Now I am moving it into the main domain and I will be using custom pages. However, i don't want to have .PHP extension on the custom pages that I created. **Ex. domain.com/page.php**

I will need to remove .PHP extensions from specific pages and redirect these pages to non .PHP versions.

I just want to double check if this is the right 301 redirect for the search engines, before i publish it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mypage$ mypage.php [L]
Redirect 301 /mypage.php https: //domain.com/mypage
```

It works perfectly when i type **domain.com/mypage.php** redirects to **domain.com/mypage** But i am not sure if it's the right way to do it for the search engines. Currently i use wordpress in the root domain, so basically, I want to match the same links.

Thanks!

Comment: See this https://helponnet.com/2020/02/04/remove-html-and-php-extension-with-htaccess-rewriterule-url-rewriting-tips/

Answer (score 1):

Just use this to redirect `xyz.php` to `xyz`:

```
Redirect 301 /xyz.php /xyz
```

As far as I know about search engines, its better to use a `302` redirect to avoid a '*permanent*' issue.

Make sure that `/xyz` actually shows a valid page. So that you do not mess up with the search engines due to a simple mistake like that.

In your example, you use both [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html). One of them is enough.

- `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule`... are from [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`... are from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

Always, test it once before working on a production server.

Comment: If I use only /xyz.php when i type domain.com/xyz.php still will be opened. The way i have it now redirects to /xyz But I'm afraid more about the search engines.

Comment: @businezz what are you afraid about search engines?

Comment: From dropping the pages. I have them ranked on the first page on Google already.

Comment: @businezz, so is that good or bad? P.S: If my answer helps, you can upvote it, accept it, etc.

Comment: Well, the way i have these redirects works the way i want, but my question was if it's the correct way for the search engines.